# Win32 API - Ctrl A + Ctrl C

Tags: winapi

```
 uint x = 0x00000001;
 uint y = 0x00FF00FD;
 NativeMethods.PostMessage(hwnd, NativeMethods.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, x, y);
 NativeMethods.PostMessage(hwnd, NativeMethods.WM_LBUTTONUP, x, y);
```

Using the above statements I'm able to click in a selected area on an external window application. Now, I need to send a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> to the window.

Can you please tell me how to do this using Win32 api.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you be better served by sending a `WM_GETTEXT` to get the actual text in the window? Applications that rely on mouse/keyboard emulation are brittle at best.

Comment: NativeMethods.AttachThreadInput(processId, currentThreadId, true);

int focussed = NativeMethods.GetFocus();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(500);

              NativeMethods.SendMessage(focussed, WM_GETTEXT, builder.Capacity, builder);

Comment: Get rid of `AttachThreadInput` and use `GetForegroundWindow` instead of `GetFocus`. The `WM_GETTEXT` message seems alright, double check that builder is `out`. Also check the handles being passed around.

Comment: And be careful that you're asking for the window's text, ie the window title bar. You have to do some navigation to reach a text box or whatever it is you're trying to catch.

Comment: StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(500);
NativeMethods.SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, builder.Capacity, builder);

Comment: builder contains the title text, but not the content of the window

Comment: I don't want the title bar text, but I need the contents of the window. Any help appreciated

Comment: I told you, you have to navigate the window list. Get something like Spy++ to see what the window tree structure is like, then navigate it with `GetWindow`.